# How to load Wiris plugin in Tinymce 4

Tags: plugins, tinymce-4

I am about using Wiris with Tinymce. Following the tutorial at [INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS: WIRIS PLUGIN FOR TINYMCE](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/tinymce)
, I am unable to go over step 4.

Each time I load the plugins tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor, tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry, and  tiny_mce_wiris_CAS, the Tinymce text editor does no longer appear.

Here is my code sample

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/editor_plugin.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: "image imagetools tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry tiny_mce_wiris_CAS"
});
</script>
```

I wish to know the right way to to it.

This is the error I get in my javascript console

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - .../assets/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor/plugin.min.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - .../assets/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris_CAS/plugin.min.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - .../assets/js/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry/plugin.min.js"
```

Comment: What do you see in the browser's JavaScript console?  I suspect that you will find errors in the editor attempting to load the Wiris plugin JavaScript files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the plugin you need to include in the plugins section on tinymce.init is **tiny_mce_wiris**. You have included the name of the buttons instead (tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor, tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry and tiny_mce_wiris_CAS).

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: "image imagetools tiny_mce_wiris"});
```

Comment: I wish to know, how do I load the buttons then? After loading the plugin following your example the buttons do not appear though there is no error message.

Comment: You need to include the buttons in your TinyMCE toolbar configuration, we would recommend that you download our ready to use demos to see a simple integration example: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/demo-download

Comment: Please update your installation tutorial. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. What do you believe is missing in the installation tutorial?

Comment: I included it by editing you answer. Did you see it?

Comment: Both the name of the plugin and the buttons are described at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/tinymce

Comment: @WIRISMATHsupportteam I am using TinyMCE with angular 4. Is there any way in which I can use wiris ? I don't see any steps for using wiris with angular.

Comment: You can use TinyMCE and Angular as described at https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angularjs/. Then you can install WIRIS plugin normally in TinyMCE or use it as an external plugin (http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/resources/external-plugin).

Comment: why the keyboard is not working in only draw function is working http://fiddle.tinymce.com/oxdaab/637?_ga=2.176280165.1375130121.1592377703-1693941266.1592377703 please help

Answer (score 3):

Apart from downloading and using TinyMCE plugin , you can even use Wiris as externally hosted plugin. 
I followed this documentation http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/resources/external-plugin

My component looked like following, and I was able to get Wiris to work this way.

`<editor apiKey="test" [init]="{ plugins : 'image', external_plugins: { tiny_mce_wiris: 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js' }, toolbar: 'tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor' } "></editor>`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in answer above you forgot to add this into  tinymce.init :

```
toolbar: 'tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor'
```